# How to disallow further installations in different directories with QtIFW

Tags: qt, installation, qt-installer

My QtIFW-Installer works fine so far. But I can install the same application multiple times in different Locations. How can I detect, that the application is already installed in another or the same location and block installation in this case?

I'm looking for a scripting solution.

BTW I use the CMake integration.